# cropped preview in android camera2

Tags: android-camera2

I’ve spend a few days struggling to find a way to get the full preview/photo from the API camera2. When I take a picture from the default camera application or with any application using the old API I got the full picture in preview or by taking the photo. But all the applications using camera2 I tried are cutting the left and right borders.
I tried a lots of things to solve this case like setting the zoom at 0, changing the sizes of the preview or the capture, changing the ratio, the templates, the format of pictures but the result is still cropped and I don’t know why. Is there a problem in my code? Is this a specificity of the API and does the same with all devices? Or is it just my tablet that as some kind of incompatibility?
Here is the preview I have using my application:
[cutted preview with camera2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5N3x.png)
Here is the preview I have when using the default camera application:
[full preview with default application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrGFa.png)
This is a sample of code with which I have the problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

{

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 201;
private TextureView surfaceCamera;
private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
private Size imageDimension;
private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;


CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera)
    {
        cameraDevice = camera;
        createCameraPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }
        cameraDevice = null;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    surfaceCamera = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceCamera);
    surfaceCamera.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
        {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture)
        {

        }
    });
}
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION:
        {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                openCamera();//manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            return;
        }
        default:
            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
    }
}

private void openCamera()
{
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try
    {
        String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        assert map != null;
        imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }
        manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
    }
    catch (CameraAccessException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void createCameraPreview()
{
    try
    {
        SurfaceTexture texture = surfaceCamera.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                //The camera is already closed
                if (null == cameraDevice)
                {
                    return;
                }
                // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                updatePreview();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession)
            {

            }
        }, null);
    }
            catch (CameraAccessException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void updatePreview()
{
    try
    {
        cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
    }
    catch (CameraAccessException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is what i mean by cropped : [compared picture](https://goopics.net/i/91do3).

Comment: Hi. Instead of put additional information on comments, please, edit your post and complete it.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually resolved the problem... by installing the last version of android on the tablet. It also fixes an out of memory exception.

EDIT :
My bad, by upgrading the android version form 6.0 to 7.1, the device level switch to legacy (it was limited). So the camera just use the old api throw camera2. For information i'm using a galaxy tab A 6 (2016) 10'1.